# How do i setup BroadcastReceiver to only display sms received from specific numbers?

Tags: broadcastreceiver

I need help modifying a broadcastReceiver I wrote so that it only displays incoming sms message from numbers that I can specify. right now the following code displays ALL received sms, it would be nice if the app only displayed sms from 1 specific number. can anyone provide any specifics on how I could accomplish this?

code is as follows:

```
public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {

   final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

      // Retrieves a map of extended data from the intent.
      final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

      try {

          if (bundle != null) {

              final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

              for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

                  SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                  String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                  String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                  String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                  Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: "+ senderNum + "; message: " + message);


                 // Show Alert
                  int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                  Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, 
                             "senderNum: "+ senderNum + ", message: " + message, duration);
                  toast.show();

              } // end for loop
            } // bundle is null

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);

    }
  }    
}
```

thanks a bunch for any help guys.

Comment: Which OS is this about?

Comment: OS? not sure the OS really matters, but if it does, this is about Android OS 4.0+.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put one if there :)

```
public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {
   private static final String MY_PHONE_NUMBER = "your number here";
   final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

      // Retrieves a map of extended data from the intent.
      final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

      try {

          if (bundle != null) {

              final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

              for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {
                  SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                  String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                  if(!MY_PHONE_NUMBER.equals(phoneNumber)) {
                      return;
                  }

                  ...
```

Comment: thanks a bunch, seems to work on the Android Studio emulator, ill update after ive debugged on a few of my dev devices to actually test this in a live environment(gonna be used on my phone thru an app at some point)